# Designing day chooser like found in clock in android L

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

[image: result I want to achieve]

I am working on an app where I want to put day chooser like below (which I saw in  clock app of android L). Anyone knows how to achieve it? Or is there any library or project implementing this is present?

Comment: Try to use shape for TextView.

Comment: can you explain? also it should be perfect circle in all screen sizes, and should consume entire width of the screen @vmarkeev

Comment: follow this link, find 'ring' shape http://android-dev-tips-and-tricks.blogspot.com/2012/09/xml-drawables-part-ii.html

Comment: You can use radio group with horizontal orientation and on selected the radio-button you can use white circle

Comment: Tried that but could not figure out how to put the text on the radiobutton @Aashvi

Comment: @Nilabja by using gravity you can put text in center. I updated code in answer section, take a look .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example by radio group which i tried. maybe its helpful for you. just take a look once.

your main xml file

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#655EF9"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/radiobtn_bck"
        android:button="@null"
        android:checked="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="S" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/radiobtn_bck"
        android:button="@null"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="M" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/radiobtn_bck"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:button="@null"
        android:text="T" />

</LinearLayout>
```

here radiobtn_bck xml in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_shape" android:state_checked="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_shape" android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_shape" android:state_focused="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_shape_purple" android:state_checked="false" />
```

bg_shape.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:shape="oval">
<solid android:color="#ffffff" />
<size
    android:width="40dp"
    android:height="40dp" />
```

bg_shape_purple.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:shape="oval">
<solid android:color="#655EF9" />
<size
    android:width="40dp"
    android:height="40dp" />
```

Comment: I need functionality like checkbox, where multiple days can be selected. are there any workaround? @Aashvi

Comment: instead of radio group, you can use linear layout  it will also give you multiple selection functionality or otherwise use checkbox.

Comment: thanks @Clairvoyant and upvote my answer happy coding !!

Comment: incomplete answer. missing tags

Comment: @SiddarthG do you want to do copy paste?