# Create toggle button group showing weekdays

Tags: android, xml

> I want to create a toggle button exactly like this image below and display all  toggle button in the same line to select weekdays for an alarm event.I have no idea regarding this.Please help.

[image]

Comment: use radio button with multi selection instead of toggle button

Comment: @Android - can we achieve the same theming as in the image shown if we use radio buttons?

Comment: yes @user3556657.. we can achieve

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33731543/designing-day-chooser-like-found-in-clock-in-android-l/33750869#33750869 refer this link

Comment: @Android Thanks man.This solves my problem.Post this as an answer.

Comment: i posted the answer. you need to change background according to your requirment.

Comment: @Android When i add more checkboxes than  7 these will be displayed outside screensize as its a linear layout.Any idea?

Comment: then use relative layout... and please upvote my answer also :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example by radio group which i tried. maybe its helpful for you. just take a look once.

your main xml file

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#655EF9"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/radiobtn_bck"
    android:button="@null"
    android:checked="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="S" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/radiobtn_bck"
    android:button="@null"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="M" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/radiobtn_bck"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:button="@null"
    android:text="T" />

</LinearLayout>
```

here radiobtn_bck xml in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_shape" android:state_checked="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_shape" android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_shape" android:state_focused="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_shape_purple" android:state_checked="false" />
```

bg_shape.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:shape="oval">
<solid android:color="#ffffff" />
<size
android:width="40dp"
android:height="40dp" />
```

bg_shape_purple.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:shape="oval">
<solid android:color="#655EF9" />
<size
android:width="40dp"
android:height="40dp" />
```

Comment: your drawable is missing root tag.

Comment: shape is missing end tags